# Polynomial maps over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

It is know that an injective polynomial map $f:\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^{n} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^{n}$ is an bijection with inverse regular (Cynk-Rusek theorem). My question is following:

Take $\mathcal{O}$ the integral closure  $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Let $F: \mathcal{O}^{n}  \longrightarrow 
 \mathcal{O}^{n}$  an injective polynomial map with $\det J_{f} =1$ (jacobian condition) and coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ . Is $F$ an invertible map?

Comment: That is true.  Your map is a morphism of schemes, $f:\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{Z}}\to \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{Z}}$.  Since the determinant of the Jacobian is invertible, the morphism $f$ is 'etale (not necessarily finite, which is the most common mistake in attempted solutions of the Jacobian conjecture).  If the induced map $F$ is injective, then $f$ is an open embedding.  If the complement is nonempty, then after reduction to some finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$, the complement has a rational point.  By the Dirichlet box principle, the reduction is non-injective, contradicting that $f$ embeds.

Comment: I just realized that injectivity of $F$ is not equivalent to injectivity of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^n \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^n$.  For instance, $F(x) = 4x^2-x$ is injective on $\mathcal{O}$, but it is not injective on $\mathbb{Q}$.  So the argument in my previous comment is incomplete.

Comment: @JasonStarr: thanks for the argument. In case, $f(x) = 4x^{2}-x$  the jacobian condition ($\det J_{f} = 1$) isn't satisfied.

Comment: Indeed, the Jacobian condition is not satisfied for $F(x)=4x^2-x$.  However, my point is that the condition regarding injectivity on $\mathcal{O}^n$ does not imply the condition regarding injectivity on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^n$.

Comment: for me it isn't clear that $F$ injective implies that $f$ is open embedding. How to prove it? Is this a general fact?

Comment: "for me it isn't clear that $F$ injective implies that $f$ is an open embedding.  How to prove it?  Is this a general fact?"  That is not true.  The example in my comment above, $F(x)=4x^2-x$, is injective, yet $f$ is not an embedding.